# How to show video title in UWP MediaPlayerElement?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, media-player

I am wondering how to show video title on top part of the screen with media transport controls. I'm using [MediaPlayerElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement) in UWP, target version 14393.

Comment: You can get the Video file name and set it to TextBlock.

Comment: But where to put the TextBlock so that it only shows when transport media control pops up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaTransportControls) do not provide a `Title` property to show video title. However, we can implement this easily as refer to [Create custom transport controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls).

Since we want to add a function to the control, we need to create a new class that derives from [MediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaTransportControls). For a detailed tutorial, please see **Create a derived control** under [Customize the transport controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls#customize-the-transport-controls). And for a complete sample, please refer to [Media Transport Controls sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlCustomMediaTransportControls).

Here, as you want the title shows on top part of the screen and only shows when 
media transport control pops up, you can add the `TextBlock` under the `Border` named "***ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border***" and set its `VerticalAlignment` to `Top` like the following:

```
<Border x:Name="ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Red" FontSize="36" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />
        <Grid x:Name="ControlPanelGrid" ...>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

And in the code-behind, you can implement a dependency property for the setting of the title.

```
public sealed class CustomMediaTransportControls : MediaTransportControls
{
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Title.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(CustomMediaTransportControls), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public CustomMediaTransportControls()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomMediaTransportControls);
    }
    ...
}
```

After this, you should be able to use your custom transport controls like:

```
<MediaPlayerElement Name="MainMPE" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Source="video.mp4">
    <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        <local:CustomMediaTransportControls x:Name="customMTC"
                                            Title="This is a title">
        </local:CustomMediaTransportControls>
    </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement>
```